# Concatenating two floats into one column in pandas

Tags: python

If I have a data frame which has float columns like below

```
Pickup_longitude    Pickup_latitude
1176807 -73.929321  40.746761
753359  -73.940964  40.679981
1378672 -73.924011  40.824677
302960  -73.845108  40.754841
827558  -73.937073  40.820759
```

I want to concatenate the lat-long as ("lat","long") in one column.

I did below code for sample three rows but I was wondering is there a faster method instead of converting to string using .astype(str). I initially tried using str() but that also takes the index values into it.

```
trip_data_sample['lat_long_pickup']=trip_data_sample["Pickup_latitude"][:3].astype(str)+","+\
trip_data_sample["Pickup_longitude"].astype(str)
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good method -- readable and efficient, using standard pandas methods. I don't think there's any reason to expect another function to convert to string more quickly than .astype(str). Are you seeing actual performance problems, or just trying to find the fastest method?

Answer (score 2):

You could create tuples using a list comprehension and indexing the dataframe:

```
df['lat_long'] = [', '.join(str(x) for x in y) for y in map(tuple, df[['Pickup_latitude', 'Pickup_longitude']].values)]
```

`df` looks like this now:

```
>>> df
         Pickup_longitude  Pickup_latitude               lat_long
1176807        -73.929321        40.746761  40.746761, -73.929321
753359         -73.940964        40.679981  40.679981, -73.940964
1378672        -73.924011        40.824677  40.824677, -73.924011
302960         -73.845108        40.754841  40.754841, -73.845108
827558         -73.937073        40.820759  40.820759, -73.937073
```

Comment: It is not string. What we want is “48.355328,11.7917104”. something like this to be passed further